# BXSlider with text - showing the fourth slide on load off-centre

Tags: jquery, html, css, bxslider

I'm using BXSlider to make a really basic text slider. I've installed it, but the slider begins with the final frame and it's off-centre on load. When I change the slide or move the block it goes back to normal. Otherwise it works fine.

So far I've tried changing the minSlides, maxSlides and slideWidth settings but this hasn't worked. maxSlides did change the location of the text but I couldn't get it centred.

On load: (link removed - need more reputation).

After interacting with the slide: https://i.stack.imgur.com/01vcf.png

EDIT:

Issue only occurs when this plugin: https://github.com/daneden/animate.css is activated for the body class. This was done using:

```
<body class="animated zoomInUp">
```

Is there some way I can pause the slider startup until the animation finishes?

Comment: You will never get bxSlider correctly until you fix the rest of your code. You should read the following: [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve]. If you can do that, I'll even help you with the rest of your mess.

Comment: If there's something broken in the rest of the code it would be really great if you could point me in the right direction. Or do you mean I need to make it less messy? I appreciate the help documents - after reading them I've narrowed down the issue and have updated the OP.

Comment: Not really a good [mcve], but you look serious about your issue. Review my answer and keep in mind that the code I post will function on it's own. If you were to just cut and paste it in a cookie cutter site like WordPress or some CMS, results may vary. There are details in the demo itself. In the CSS, the comments are in CAPS, but I'm not yelling, it's just that way so it's noticeable. If the answer helped remember to accept the answer by clicking the ✔.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update 2

OP needs more fundamental knowledge of JavaScript/jQuery in order to even implement this code. In order to expedite this solution to OP, Demo 2 is basically Demo 1 but consolidated on one webpage. If Demo 2 was copied and pasted on a blank text file, then it's extension changed from `.txt` to `.html`, then opened in a **modern browser** *, it would function with no extra requirements.

*IE is not a serious browser, it's a little hobby of M$, but it should run in IE as well. The JavaScript I added is totally old school.

### Update 1

OP requested a way to delay bxSlider instantiation so that the body can be animated when loading the page.

- The animation from animate.css transition duration is slow (it's to be expected because it looks nice with easing.) So the first step is to use the latest loading event:

> ```
> window.onload
> ```

- The best way to prepare a function to load on `window.onload` is to wrap it in a named function. **Important Syntax**: You must remove the parenthesis of the function if you use `window.onload`

> ```
> window.onload = init;
> ```

- Even though `window.onload` is the slowest event to start loading bxSlider, it isn't enough time. So we need to add a `setTimeout`.

> ```
>  function init() {
>       setTimeout(function() {
>         var bx = $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
>       }, 3500);
>    }
>    window.onload = init;
> ```

**Details are commented in updated demo**

---

The demo has corrected HTML and CSS. With the original code, I doubt that the fix for bxSlider would work. You need to really familiarize yourself with some HTML and CSS tutorials or at the very least use [W3Schools](http://w3schools.com) as a reference (they have an abundance of tutorials and examples but not the best.)

<kbd>**[Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/NqtxD8q4q549vn0fu9W0/)**</kbd>

### Demo 1

```js
function init() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var bx = $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
  }, 3500);
}

window.onload = init;
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* DO NOT USE SO MANY FONT FAMILIES UNLESS YOU KNOW WHAT YOU ARE DOING*/


/* USE 2 AT THE MOST. ONE FOR TITLES AND ONE FOR NORMAL USE*/

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito|PT+Sans:700');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}

body {
  font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

main {
  padding: 30px 0 0;
}

section {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

p {
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0 10px 10px;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.slider {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

[class*='title'] {
  font-family: "PT Sans";
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #00aee8;
}

.title {
  font-size: 48px;
}

.subtitle {
  background-color: #ef233c;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 15px;
}

.boxtext {
  background-color: #ef233c;
  font-size: 32px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.bodytext {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #160C28;
}

.btctitle {
  font-size: 48px;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #FF3;
}

footer {
  padding: 10px 5px 40px;
  margin-top: 0;
}

footer p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}

a,
a:link,
a:visited {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover,
a:active,
a:focus {
  color: transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-shadow: -.25px -.25px 0 #fc0, -.25px .25px 0 #fc0, .25px -.25px 0 #fc0, .25px .25px 0 #fc0;
}

a.x::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fc0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out 0s;
}

a.x:hover::before,
a.x:active::before,
a.x:focus::before {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.btcbutton {
  font-size: 48px;
  background: rgba(255, 200, 12, 1);
}


/* THE LAST TWO RULESETS IS THE ANSWER BUT WILL MOST LIKELY
|| NOT WORK CORRECTLY WITH THE ORIGINAL CSS and HTML. THE
|| PADDING MIN-HEIGHT IS BY PREFERENCE
*/

.bx-wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.bxslider li {
  padding: 0 55px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Practical Applications</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/animatecss/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
  <link href="CSS.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.css' rel='stylesheet'>
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body class="animated zoomInUp">
  <header>
    <h1>
      <a href="index.html">
        <img src="https://wemakewebsites.com/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/post_images/headline/bitcoin-logo-with-padding.png?itok=mnfN-yoC" width="100%" height="100">
      </a>
    </h1>

    <nav>
      <ul class='boxtext'>

        <li class="subtitle"><a href="How.html" title="How does it work?" class='x'>How?</a></li>
        <li class="subtitle"><a href="Why.html" title="Why use a blockchain?" class='x'>Why?</a></li>
        <li class="subtitle"><a href="Practical_Applications.html" title="Practical Applications" class='x'>What?</a></li>

      </ul>
    </nav>


    <h2 class="title">Practical Applications</h2>
  </header>
  <main>
    <section class="bodytext">
      <p>So far, blockchains have been as a ledger of transactions. Cryptocurrencies, as they are termed, are favoured as transactions are stored across the blockchain. This make it impossible for a government or a bank to interfere with transaction history,
        and it's almost impossible for the blockchain to be compromised or lost like a bank database could be.</p>
      <p>Here are some problems that you need to be aware of:</p>

      <!-- slider -->
    </section>
    <section class='slider'>
      <ul class="bxslider">
        <li class="bodytext">
          You obviously put some effort into this code. Why not put some effort into learning how to do it simple first. Every style you add to the stylesheet compounds your problem.

        </li>
        <li class="bodytext">
          Don't use table, tr, and th for layout. You didn't add an end tag for h1. center tags are not supported in HTML5. id='top' is an id, id must be unique. id='top' is used on 3 different tags. Do not do that. Change it to class='top'.

        </li>
        <li class="bodytext">
          CSS link tags must be before any script tags. Script tags should be placed before the closing end tag of body. Do not use position:absolute without wrapping it in element that has position:relative.

        </li>
        <li class="bodytext">
          CSS.css file is commented with corrections. You need to know the fundamentals, Google search: "CSS tutorial"

        </li>
        <li class="bodytext">
          At the beginning of page, only !doctype html is needed for HTML5. Why would you use HTML4? You need to know the fundamentals, Google search: "HTML5 tutorial"

        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <p>Let's explore the most well-known utilisation of blockchain technology to date:</p>

    <p>
      <a href="Bitcoin.html" class="btcbutton x"> <span>Bitcoin</span>
      </a>
    </p>
  </footer>


  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.min.js'></script>

</body>

</html>
```

### Demo 2

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Practical Applications</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/animatecss/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.css' rel='stylesheet'>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito|PT+Sans:700" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      border: 0;
    }
    
    html,
    body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%
    }
    
    body {
      font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
      font-size: 16px;
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    
    main {
      padding: 30px 0 0;
    }
    
    section {
      padding: 10px 20px;
    }
    
    p {
      line-height: 1.5;
      margin: 0 10px 10px;
    }
    
    li {
      list-style: none;
    }
    
    h1 {
      margin-top: 30px;
    }
    
    .slider {
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    [class*='title'] {
      font-family: "PT Sans";
      text-align: center;
      color: #FFF;
      background-color: #00aee8;
    }
    
    .title {
      font-size: 48px;
    }
    
    .subtitle {
      background-color: #ef233c;
      font-size: 24px;
      margin: 15px;
    }
    
    .boxtext {
      background-color: #ef233c;
      font-size: 32px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-around;
      align-items: center;
    }
    
    .bodytext {
      font-size: 18px;
      color: #160C28;
    }
    
    .btctitle {
      font-size: 48px;
      color: #000;
      background-color: #FF3;
    }
    
    footer {
      padding: 10px 5px 40px;
      margin-top: 0;
    }
    
    footer p {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 18px;
    }
    
    a,
    a:link,
    a:visited {
      position: relative;
      color: #fff;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    a:hover,
    a:active,
    a:focus {
      color: transparent;
      background-color: transparent;
      text-shadow: -.25px -.25px 0 #fc0, -.25px .25px 0 #fc0, .25px -.25px 0 #fc0, .25px .25px 0 #fc0;
    }
    
    a.x::before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 2px;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      background-color: #fc0;
      visibility: hidden;
      transform: scaleX(0);
      transition: all .5s ease-in-out 0s;
    }
    
    a.x:hover::before,
    a.x:active::before,
    a.x:focus::before {
      visibility: visible;
      transform: scaleX(1);
    }
    
    .btcbutton {
      font-size: 48px;
      background: rgba(255, 200, 12, 1);
    }
    
    .bx-wrapper {
      margin: 0 auto;
      min-height: 100px;
    }
    
    .bxslider li {
      padding: 0 55px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      text-align: center;
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1 class="animated zoomInUp">
      <a href="index.html">
        <img src="https://wemakewebsites.com/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/post_images/headline/bitcoin-logo-with-padding.png?itok=mnfN-yoC" width="100%" height="100">
      </a>
    </h1>

    <nav>
      <ul class='boxtext'>

        <li class="subtitle"><a href="How.html" title="How does it work?" class='x'>How?</a></li>
        <li class="subtitle"><a href="Why.html" title="Why use a blockchain?" class='x'>Why?</a></li>
        <li class="subtitle"><a href="Practical_Applications.html" title="Practical Applications" class='x'>What?</a></li>

      </ul>
    </nav>


    <h2 class="title">Practical Applications</h2>
  </header>
  <main>
    <section class="bodytext">
      <p>So far, blockchains have been as a ledger of transactions. Cryptocurrencies, as they are termed, are favoured as transactions are stored across the blockchain. This make it impossible for a government or a bank to interfere with transaction history,
        and it's almost impossible for the blockchain to be compromised or lost like a bank database could be.</p>
      <p>Here are some problems that you need to be aware of:</p>

      <!-- slider -->
    </section>
    <section class='slider'>
      <ul class="bxslider">
        <li class="bodytext">
          You obviously put some effort into this code. Why not put some effort into learning how to do it simple first. Every style you add to the stylesheet compounds your problem.

        </li>
        <li class="bodytext">
          Don't use table, tr, and th for layout. You didn't add an end tag for h1. center tags are not supported in HTML5. id='top' is an id, id must be unique. id='top' is used on 3 different tags. Do not do that. Change it to class='top'.

        </li>
        <li class="bodytext">
          CSS link tags must be before any script tags. Script tags should be placed before the closing end tag of body. Do not use position:absolute without wrapping it in element that has position:relative.

        </li>
        <li class="bodytext">
          CSS.css file is commented with corrections. You need to know the fundamentals, Google search: "CSS tutorial"

        </li>
        <li class="bodytext">
          At the beginning of page, only !doctype html is needed for HTML5. Why would you use HTML4? You need to know the fundamentals, Google search: "HTML5 tutorial"

        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <p>Let's explore the most well-known utilisation of blockchain technology to date:</p>

    <p>
      <a href="Bitcoin.html" class="btcbutton x"> <span>Bitcoin</span>
      </a>
    </p>
  </footer>


  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.min.js'></script>
  <script>
    function init() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        var bx = $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
      }, 3500);
    }

    window.onload = init;
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I really appreciate the time you've put into redoing the code. What I didn't make clear because I misused the h1 tag rather than changing the body class was that the entire page was supposed to have the animated effect. Yes I know this is a terrible UX decision. I can replicate the issue using your code by changing the body class to "animated zoomInUp". Using a different effect like "animated bounce" is fine. So my belief is that my code isn't the cause, but using that effect is breaking the slider on load which is why I asked if there was some way to pause it until the page had "zoomInUp"'d.

Comment: @user16421 Got it, see update. It works surprisingly well.

Comment: Thanks again. One more thing - how is the snippet above implementing the separate js at the top? To get it working on my machine, do I need to reference it as an external scripts.js file at the top of the document so it runs first or in <script> tags somewhere else? I've tried both but it's not running so I'm probably trying to implement it all wrong. I'll be sure to look into jQuery some more so I at least kind of know what I'm doing in the future.

Comment: @user16421 Read Update 2 in order to get Demo 2 to function outside the snippet. **Do not change anything**, just copy and paste the whole code as it is explained in Update 2. Once you have that **single page running in a browser**, then you should examine the code and make note of where: 1. `<link>` is placed **exactly** 2. `<style>` is placed **exactly** 3. `<script src=....>` is placed **exactly** 4. `<script>... is placed **exactly** Don't forget to click the ✔ of this post if this has resolved your problem.

Comment: If it hasn't, then you'll need to explain more details as to how you are situated with your host or if you are just using localhost, what type of computer you are using, etc.

Comment: I got it working! However, there seems to be a noticeable delay where the list is displayed generically before the js loads in which occurs on the demo 1 and 2 snippet and on my version. I tried reducing the delay but as I approach around 800 ticks the slider loads off-centre, I can't find a value where it's smooth. I know that your fix is supposed to delay the load in but I am sure I didn't see this effect when testing your snippet before your most recent update. If I'm wrong and it's a consequence of the fix that's fair enough, let me know and I'll mark this as resolved.

Comment: You are correct, sir. Review the [first Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/NqtxD8q4q549vn0fu9W0/),  but it didn't apply the animation on the `<body>` only the `<h1>`. Although it's possible to animate the `<body>` and load bxSlider afterwards, it's too tricky to get it so there's no FOUC (Flash Of Unstyled Content). One way to mask FOUC is to fade in the content, which I decided against doing because it might chew up the animation if it is too late or never happen because bxSlider is too early.

Comment: When using jQuery UI, the most optimal speed for animation is 750ms. Try 900ms, I use that for jQuery UI animation when I use it in conjunction with other similar plugins. There's also the common technique of hiding the body then revealing it around the timeframe of when the FOUC happens.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug affecting chrome in particular, that I usually can fix with the following:

```
.bx-viewport li {
    min-height: 1px;
    min-width: 1px;
}
```

I override it in my stylesheet file which I link after the bxslider css file, like I did here https://kensetsutenshokunavi.jp/. In this case I also hided the slider till images are loaded because the were quite heavy and broke the layout for some reason.

I suggest also to give the slides container width and or height if possible. I cannot suggest any further without checking your code. I hope it helps anyway.

Comment: I'm still getting the issue with that fix on Chrome, IE and Firefox. Safari works fine. Without the change the same is true. Is this how the CSS should look? I didn't have a .bx-viewport li by default  http://imgur.com/kWRyyZE

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried the override CSS and nothing happened. I then made a new class for my div to set width/height - didn't fix it but weirdly the height setting didn't change the slider's height but the width setting did. Here's the code, sorry it's messy I don't really know what I'm doing. HTML: https://pastebin.com/XGU6ZfFw CSS (relevant stuff at the bottom): https://pastebin.com/HiRG3wgi

Comment: I've narrowed down the issue and updated the OP - no need to waste your time sifting through that code.